# jetpack infinite scroll and isotope relayout

Tags: scroll, infinite, jetpack, jquery-isotope

How to relayout page when new elements are added by infinite scroll.

jetpack said you can relayout page with this event. (we trigger an event after posts are appended. To make use of this event, simply catch the post-load event when it fires on document.body:)

`( function( $ ) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'post-load', function () {
        // New posts have been added to the page.
    } );
} )( jQuery );`

How to relayout page with isotope. I am using isotope for masonry layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document.body ).on( 'post-load', function () {
    $container.masonry().isotope( {
        resizable: true,
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode : 'masonry',
        gutter: 0
    } );
    $container.isotope('reloadItems');
    isotope( 'reLayout', true );

} );
```